# Windows 10 user ID seen on share from Synology

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I have a Synology DS1513+ running DSM5.0-4493 update 1 (a several-year-old OS).

I have Windows 7 and 10 laptops mounting that disk, along with a Linux laptop mounting the same area via NFS.

My development account on the Linux box and Synology is user ID 1000.

I'd like my Windows boxes to present that user ID as well so they have full permission to edit everything, create and delete files etc.  (I develop software that is intended to work on both OS's so edit and build on both OS's.)

On the Windows 7 box long ago I apparently also set it's user ID to 1000 somehow, but on the Windows 10 box I'm user ID 4294967294.  How can I change that to 1000?

When I "map network drive" I've tried checking "mount with different credentials," expecting it'd ask me for an alternate user ID, but it doesn't seem to ever query WHAT different credentials to use.  (I also c
an't think why the disk would take my word for it that I should be user 1000.)

I've also tried `net use V: \\diskstation\volume1\MyDisk MyPassword /USER:SynologyUserName` and am told:

```
You can't connect to the file share because it's not secure. This
share requires the obsolete SMB1 protocol, which is unsafe and could
expose your system to attack. Your system requires SMB2 or higher. For
more info on resolving this issue, see:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=852747
```

I've also tried going to Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager\Add a Windows Credential, and typing the share \diskstation\volume1\MyDisk, MyUser, and MyPassword.  Upon OK:

```
This information cannot be 
saved.  Make sure all the information is correct and that all required fields are completed.

Error code: 0x80070057
Error Message: The parameter is incorrect.
```

I've also tried share as simply diskstation.  Upon OK, it is accepted, and appears on Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager as "diskstation" under Windows Credentials.  But then I unmount and remount the share, try creating a file, and the UID is still 4294967294, not the 1000 of the name of the credential I created.

I've also googled for "map synology user ID."  Not finding anything useful.

I've ssh'd in and did `find` from `/` for any config files with samba in the name and don't find anything.  (Well, two tiny files, but don't seem to be samba.conf or anything for mapping users.)

I've also searched systematically through the synology's control panel over the http interface and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your Synology box almost certainly is running [Samba](https://www.samba.org) as the "Windows file sharing protocols" implementation.

In Samba, there's a concept called UID mapping, which maps Windows-style SIDs (long strings of numbers that are auto-generated under the hood when you make a new user in Windows) to UNIX-style UIDs (which usually start with small numbers like 1000 and increase into 6 digits for certain systems).

This is because Windows SIDs, which are the numerical identifiers for Windows accounts, are fundamentally different from UNIX UIDs, which are the numerical identifiers of UNIX accounts. They have different formats, and changing a Windows SID isn't easy (whereas it's quite easy to change a UNIX UID with root permissions).

Here's an example of the format of a Windows SID: `S-1-5-21-1180699209-877415012-3182924384-500`

The reason we have to "map" between SIDs and UIDs is, even if you *tried* to change a Windows SID to something like `1000`, it wouldn't work, because Windows expects SIDs for users to be of a certain length and syntax, including beginning with an "S" and having a bunch of long numbers with dashes in them.

If it's sufficiently old, it's probably running Samba 3. UID mapping in Samba3 is discussed [here](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/old/Samba3-HOWTO/idmapper.html).

UID mapping in Samba4 is conceptually the same, but implemented by your choice of "identity mapping backend" -- see [here](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Identity_Mapping_Back_Ends).

Here's how to do identity mapping on a Samba4 domain controller: [here](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configuring_Winbindd_on_a_Samba_AD_DC).

However, wiki articles aside (they provide very useful conceptual information so you understand what's going on under the hood), the most useful information I could find specifically about this combination of things:

- Windows file shares
- Synology
- Mapping of clients to users on the Synology box

... is in **[this answer over on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/269653/69511)**, which deals with user *names*, not user *IDs*.

[image]

If you found that information useful, you should click through the link to AskUbuntu above, and toss Aaron an upvote for his good answer.

The key insight to take away from Aaron's answer is that, if your Windows username and password exactly match the Synology server user's username and password, you'll be able to get in without even performing any manual authentication (you won't have to enter any username/password), and from the Synology side, the UID you'll have for file/directory permissions will be set based on the UID of the user on the *Synology* side who has the same user *name* as your Windows account.

---

Another reason it probably doesn't work on Windows 10: If you log into Windows 10 with your Microsoft account, your user name isn't actually what you think it is! Your user name is your Microsoft account email address, under the hood; it just *appears* to be whatever "friendly" username you gave it in Win32 land (like you have the folder, `C:\Users\swissfrank` instead of `C:\Users\swiss.frank@gmail.com`).

So when you hit the Synology server with a username of `swiss.frank@gmail.com` (instead of the user `swissfrank` which has been properly created on the Synology side as UNIX user ID 1000), it treats you as a different user. This is by design, and definitely means you'd need a user name map like in Aaron's answer. The contents would be something like:

`swissfrank = swiss.frank@gmail.com`

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm old-school and never happier when I can edit a config file instead of using a GUI.  But when I ssh into my diskstation, there's no samba.conf that `find` can find, and indeed only two little files with samba in the name.

Comment: How about smb.conf ?

Comment: OK, I have /etc/init/smbd.conf, but it's just run-level start/stop of course.  No other file under /etc contains '*smb*'.

Comment: Hmm... maybe your Synology being extremely old has something to do with it, because those samba conf files *are* there for the other guy running Synology DiskStation on AskUbuntu.

Comment: fair enough but again i have it working for the old win 7 box, so it seems possible with the OS the disk currently has

Comment: Did you confirm whether you're (trying to) login to the Synology box with a Microsoft Account? (see my edits to my post at the bottom for details)

Comment: I've reread your post but I don't think I see how to confirm?

Comment: Might wanna hang out in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) to do the extended troubleshooting that's needed for this. If no one responds, just wait a while.